# Python Data Structure Graph

Tags: python, data-structures, trace

I would like to take a python script as well as a data type as input. Then, I would like to output a graph or set of graphs that illustrate the evolution for every object instantiated of that particular data type in the python script.

For example, suppose I had created two dictionaries in my python script. **Dictionary a** would be passed to a function where it was transformed. Therefore, **Dictionary a** would have a two node directed graph.
Parallel to that graph, would be the one for **Dictionary b** where it is a single node because no transformation was applied.

In order to solve this problem, I came up with a naive two step approach.

1. Make one pass through the code to check if a new dictionary is being created or if one is being modified via a function based on static analysis. And add code to check runtime data types that writes to stdout.
2. Run the modified script and collect output to interpret the evolution of the dictionaries and create graph

Is there a better approach to do this type of data type tracking via python?

Thanks!

Comment: You can post your code, attempt.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [Data Flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), a common topic in compilers. Since Python provides a host of tools for accessing the internals of the compiler, I'd suggest you look at, e.g., the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#module-ast) module.

Comment: @AustinHastings I didn't realize how difficult this is to actually do. Extracting data types from the ast is in fact quite difficult and must be inferred :P

Comment: @user2253546 yes. There's probably a PhD available if you do a good job of whatever you're doing. ;-)